# Splitting a string up and joining it back together in reverse order

Tags: c#

I want to be able to take a sentence and split it and change the positioning of the words to put the sentence into reverse, there is no set amount of words in the sentence.

Example 1:

```
Input: "This is a test"
Output: "test a is This"
```

Example 2:

```
Input: "Hello World"
Output: "World Hello"
```

I have been trying for a while now, all I have working is

```
var stringreversed = stringinput.Split(" ");
```

But I have no idea where to go from here.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Could you please show us what you have tried to far and what you need help with specifically.

Comment: `string result = string.Join(" ", "This is a test".Split(' ').Reverse());`. Add using for `System.Linq` to access `Reverse` extension method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `String.Split()` to split the string, then use `Array.Reverse()` to reverse the resulting array:

```
var input = "This is a test";

// Split defaults to splitting on whitespace when you don't supply any arguments
var words = input.Split();

// Reverse the order of the words
Array.Reverse(words);

// Turn back into a string
var reversed = String.Join(" ", words);
```

Answer (score 1):

These actions are equal. You can use different function steps or link them all together:

```
        var s = "This is a string";
        var split = s.Split(' ');
        var reversed = split.Reverse();
        var joined = string.Join(' ', reversed);
        Console.WriteLine(joined); // output: "string a is This"

        var allAtOnce = string.Join(' ', s.Split(' ').Reverse());
        Console.WriteLine(allAtOnce); // output: "string a is This"
```

Good luck.